# How can I add new plugins in CkEditor 5 with react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ckeditor, ckeditor5

I am using CkEditor 5 with ReactJS. I find it really difficult adding custom plugins...

1. I install the package code block for example with `npm i @ckeditor/ckeditor5-code-block`.
   In the ClassicEditor class (typescript file),
2. I import the module in the class like in the documentation `import CodeBlock from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-code-block/src/codeblock';`
3. In the buildinPlugin config and the defaultConfig I add the plugin

```
// Plugins to include in the build.
ClassicEditor.builtinPlugins = [
    Essentials,
    UploadAdapter,
    Autoformat,
    Bold,
    Italic,
    BlockQuote,
    EasyImage,
    Heading,
    Image,
    ImageCaption,
    ImageStyle,
    ImageToolbar,
    ImageUpload,
    Link,
    List,
    Paragraph,
    CodeBlock
];

// Editor configuration.
ClassicEditor.defaultConfig = {
    toolbar: {
        items: [
            'heading',
            '|',
            'bold',
            'italic',
            'link',
            'bulletedList',
            'numberedList',
            'uploadImage',
            'blockQuote',
            'undo',
            'redo',
            'codeblock'
        ]
    },
```

4. I build the code with npm run build and restart the server. But nothing works. The icons even are not added, I am not getting not even a small warning...
   [image]

I really dont have any ideea what to do.